# Relation between the Range(I+A) and Range(A)?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and consider
$$A:D(A) \subset H \to H $$
to be unbounded linear monotone operator.

> Is there any relation between $\mathrm{Range}(I+A)$ and $\mathrm{Range}(A)$, generally?

Definition of monotone operator: A is said to be monotone if it satisfies
$$ (Au,u) \geq 0, \quad \forall u \in D(A). $$

Some hint:
When the Range of $I+A$ is $H$, then $A$ is called maximal monotone operator which enjoys the following properties:

I) $D(A)$ is dense in $H$.

II) $A$ is a closed operator.

III) For any $\lambda>0$, $(I+\lambda A)$ is bijective from $D(A)$ onto $H$, $(I+\lambda A)^{-1}$ is a bounded operator, and its operator norm is equal or less than $1$.

I think from a continuity or a fixed point argument, we could prove that $I+A$ is surjective iff $A$ is surjective.

Comment: Is $H$ a Hilbert space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$? More specifically, are monotone operators necessarily symmetric in this context?

Comment: To your last paragraph, the statement "$I + A$ is surjective iff $A$ is surjective" fails even for operators over finite dimensional (Hilbert) spaces

Comment: @ Ben Grossman: $H$ is Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$. About the definition of monotonicity, the symmetry isn't indicated, and only the non-negativity of the above term, $(Au,u)$, is considered.

Comment: @Ben Grossman: Even if $A$ to be maximal monotone? I mean about the comment you mentioned that in the finite dimension it fails to be correct ....

Comment: Great. My point regarding symmetry is that if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space, then the fact that $(Au,u)$ is real for all $u \in H$ implies that $A$ is symmetric (e.g. as a consequence of the polarization identity).

Comment: One finite dimensional example is as follows: take $A$ over $\Bbb R^2$ (equipped with the dot-product) to be the transformation associated with the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 0}.
$$
$A$ seems to be "maximal monotone" by your definition. However, $I + A$ is surjective and $A$ fails to be surjective.

Comment: Never mind, I seem to have misunderstood property III, which my example fails to satisfy.

Comment: If $A$ is maximal monotone, doesn't property III imply that $I + A$ is surjective (since we can take $\lambda = 1$)?

Comment: @ Ben Grossman: Thanks. Your example is correct in finite.

Comment: @Ben Grossman: How about Range(I+A)=H, then Range(A)=H? Or about the converse of we furthur assume that A is strictyle monotone?

Comment: My example has $\operatorname{Range}(I + A) = H$ but $\operatorname{Range}(A) \neq H$, so no to one direction.

Comment: If $A$ is maximal monotone, then $\operatorname{range}(A)$ is automatically $H$ by property III.